# Convert json to array in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json

I'm trying to convert my json object into array. I've saw many questions on SO but that didn't help me.

My PHP Code :

```
$arr = Array ( [1] => 10 [5] => 20 ) //array key is random
```

I want to assign above array to jQuery variable.

Jquery Code :

```
var obj = '<?php echo json_encode($arr)?>';
```

when i print `obj` it gives me `{"1":"10","5":"20"}`. i want result in array like [1:10,5:20].

And after that i want to access array values by its key (e.g. `obj[1] or obj[5]`)

Ignore my syntax error.

Thanks.

Comment: use json_decode() function

Comment: var encodedJson = '<?php echo json_encode($arr)?>';
var obj = $.parseJSON(encodedJson);
alert(obj[1]); // this will show as 10

Comment: @Vaira : Mr. Engineer wants to assign the php array to javascript variable. json_decode will convert the json data to php array. Not php array to json.

Comment: @VairaMuthu It does not help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to define `var obj` without usage of `'` in script

```
<script>

var obj = <?php echo json_encode($arr)?>;
alert(obj[1]);// will alert 10

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 var data; //suppose data contains the json result i.e {"orders":[{"name":"Accessories"}}]
 var response_length=response.orders.length; //orders is the json array
  var array_store = [];
 for (i = 0; i < response_length; i++)
   array_store .push(response.orders[i].name); //name is json object
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple Solution is as below:

```
var encodedJson = '<?php echo json_encode($arr)?>'; 
var obj = $.parseJSON(encodedJson); 
alert(obj[1]); // this will show as 10
```